# android gridview with different sizes of TextViews as Item

Tags: android, gridview

I created following in Xml file

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="60dip"              
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dip"                               
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
```

and GridView item is TextView. When TextView populated content exceeds 60 dip, then it wraps vertically. because of android:columnWidth="60dip" option.

Is it possible to give android:columnWidth value based on the item populated content size?